# How can we connect to onedrive using python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, onedrive

onedrivesdk is deprecaed for python3.7.So how to connect to onedrive using python3.

Comment: https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-python This appears to support Python 3, and is the package that deprecated onedrivesdk